# Where to publish helpful, but informal papers?

Tags: publications

I have written an informal article 9 pages long, that covers some general, lightly technical material.  I wrote it because this material is not covered elsewhere, and I am knowledgeable in the field.  The material is light in the sense that it is not highly innovative, or even highly useful, but it is "good to know".  The subject matter is information security, with respect to radio systems.

I have posted the article on my personal webpage.  Should I bother to submit it somewhere for 'proper' publication?  It is not technical or innovative enough for IEEE or ACM journals (or even letters).  Or should I just keep it on my page for people with search engine inquiries related to the subject matter to possibly stumble across?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal - Anyone running or deploying radio systems.  From my background in radio, I think that many people won't use the information there, but that some will.  Overall it's interesting but not universally or extremely useful.

Comment: Does it make sense for a didactical article? (For students, amateurs, ...) Or is it more a note for yourself and colleagues?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal - It's instructive in this way: "Not many people need this, but some do, and I haven't seen it mentioned before."  An example of where it can be applied is the defense industry in radio system deployments, which is an industry that I've worked in, in the past.

Comment: Might you consider some protocol or method journals (e.g. SpringerProtocols, Methods, EPJ Plus)? Quite often the content of these types of publications are useful to some people, especially those new to the field, but do not really present any new results (and the methods have been described somewhere else, but usually just not in full detail). Alternatively, some pedagogical journals (in the style of Am. J. Phys.). I do not know about the submission process of the journals I mentioned. Finally, the omnijournal PLoS One in principle should accept everything that is technically correct.

Comment: @amlrg - Thanks, do you know of any particular protocol journals for information sciences, communications, or electrical engineering where I might find a good audience?

Comment: @amlrg, can you post that as an answer? I am in a similar situation to the OP, and your comment is very helpful to me.

Comment: @mhwombat - I was going to say the same thing, but I am having trouble finding publications of that sort in engineering.

Comment: This [new Royal Society journal](http://rsos.royalsocietypublishing.org/) might be suitable.

Comment: some journals allow review papers, and appreciate the value of (re)writing already known material in an organized and useful-to-the-new-reader way.

Comment: @adipro - I took a look at the "new Royal Society journal" and my instincts tell me it's a scam.  With things like, "we're not charging for submissions now, but we will be soon.  Take advantage of this introductory time"

Comment: I doubt a well-respected published such as the Royal Society would perpetuate a scam. From what I remember Phys. Rev. X (the new open access APS journal) was free before it had an impact factor (it takes a couple of years). Now that the impact factor is relatively high, I think they'll be charging plenty. Note that most open access journals (notably PLoS) are not free to publish in. @mhwombat My suggestions are not immediately useful for this question, as I mostly wrote about life sciences, and as such, I don't consider it an answer. For life sciences, see also Nature Protools.

Comment: @amlrg - Ok, yes I was just asking about reputation.  Yes, it must be the open access paradigm that is making them charge.  Thanks.

Comment: In my field, some journals have "tutorial" papers. To get an idea, have a look e.g. at [Brereton, R. G. & Lloyd, G. R. Support vector machines for classification and regression. Analyst, 2010, 135, 230-267. DOI 10.1039/b918972f](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/b918972f)

Comment: @horsehair It is not a scam. Royal Society journals are very reputable. [Royal Society](https://royalsociety.org/about-us/history/) has been around for very long.

Comment: _Yes, it must be the open access paradigm that is making them charge._ — Nope.  Lots of open-access journals are free both to publish in and to read.

Comment: @JeffE - Interesting.  IEEE charges over a thousand bucks to publish an open access paper in some of their publications.

Comment: I'd definitely publish it if you think it's useful and there's a legitimate venue that will publish it. Lots of people will be more likely to cite something if published anywhere. I know of appropriate avenues in the HCI world but I'm not sure about your field.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't know where to publish something, but nonetheless it is of an appropriate standard and you consider it worth sharing, why not posting it to [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/)? You won't get prestige just for submitting, but:

- people can find it,
- you can easily point to it,
- it is timestamped.

Comment: The two reasons I don't post to arXiv are 1) I don't know anyone who uses it, to invite me.  2) You can't update documents, so if I improve it later I have to have both versions there.

Comment: @horsehair 1. You don't need and invitation, you need an endorsement. Did you try to sign up? 2. People use the last version anyway.

Comment: What's the difference?  An endorsement and an invitation are the same, if I don't know anyone who can supply it.  Or am I missing something (I'm new to arXiv stuff)?

Comment: @horsehair Did you try to sign up or not? For example, I was not required to get endorsement. In any case, Internet is a big place, so maybe you can get endorsement via some people from SE, or you can mail someone you cite.

Answer (score 2):

Submit it to a conference that publishes a proceeding.  Check the ACM SIGs.  There are at least a couple that might work.

Comment: A lot of these conferences are harder to get accepted to than journals and the OP said "not technical or innovative enough for IEEE or ACM journals."

Comment: Sometimes material that's not suitable for a journal will be just the right fit for a conference, though.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:  trade journal (not an academic journal), LinkedIn article, blog post.

Answer (score 0):

An answer in a comment by alarge, who is from life sciences background:

> Might you consider some protocol or method journals (e.g. SpringerProtocols, Methods, EPJ Plus)? Quite often the content of these types of publications are useful to some people, especially those new to the field, but do not really present any new results (and the methods have been described somewhere else, but usually just not in full detail). Alternatively, some pedagogical journals (in the style of Am. J. Phys.). I do not know about the submission process of the journals I mentioned. Finally, the omnijournal PLoS One in principle should accept everything that is technically correct.

Adipro in the comments suggested https://royalsocietypublishing.org/journal/rsos

Answer (score -2):

You may try https://www.researchgate.net/

But I am not sure what their policies are.

Since I wrote this information, two people downvoted the answer, not
saying why.

But this answer is factually correct.  You can make scientific papers
available through Researchgate, and probably some that are not too
scientific. I have done so, though I would not choose Researchgate as
my primary publication medium (all of my papers there were first published on
some other venue).

Some people do get my papers through Researchgate, so it does fulfill
the dissemination purpose to some extent. I am also told by
researchgate about citations of my papers, so that I can see what
people make of them, and I can get some of the citing papers through
Researchgate. I do not really use Researchgate professionally: I am
retired. But then, the question was also for informal availability on
the web.

I know that some people do not like Researchgate for various reasons,
and possibly for opposite reasons. Mainly,  they seem to lack
resources and many of their weaknesses do not get corrected.  But they
do not ask for money as does [Academia.edu](https://academia.edu). So I use them for what they
have to give, and try to be tolerant with their failings.

One of the major problems is, as remarked in [other places](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47481), that they
do not manage well authors that have the same name. I am particularly
aware of that because my name is somewhat common. But then
Researchgate is not a reference medium.

So my advice is to be very precise on the paper itself about your name,
affiliation, and any other public information that will identify you
as a single person (using your social security number might work, but
is not advised). If the paper appeared somewhere else, try to also
give that information. And remember to be careful with copyright, and
to preferably know what you are doing in this respect (even when you
choose to disagree with some publisher).

Last remark for downvoters. My information is factually correct. So
you are really criticizing the operation of Researchgate, even though
all the user want is to make his papers accessible. It would be better and more useful
to explicitly state, however tersely in a comment, what your
objections are.

Answer (score -5):

I wouldn't bother with further publication.  You've pretty much nailed the issue:  search engines work quite well to "winnow the chaff" (to quote Rivest) when the right questioner comes along, and good security through the Petabytes of obscurity when they don't.

Comment: I don't understand what is implied by "the right questioner" or "good security" in this answer. Are you suggesting that the OP should want certain people to read the paper, and not others?

Comment: I'm suggesting that for security-related items, one doesn't generally want to have a wide audience for the material.  So to answer your question: yes.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the OP's post to suggest that the information in the paper is sensitive in any way. I **disagree strongly** with the general statement *for security-related items, one doesn't generally want to have a wide audience for the material*. I also don't see why posting it online would expose it to a narrower or more desirable audience, compared to publishing in a journal (most people find journal articles through search engines, too).

Comment: Yes, your position is quite similar to CERT, but in a more thorough analysis, CERT's policy to publish quickly and widely was started in regard to commercial software and mostly to an audience of people who had significantly more expertise than the source of problems (MSFT for example).

Comment: I have no idea who you think this will protect.

Comment: It is comparable to the question on whether information on building bombs should be readily available.  (Whether it is or isn't readily available is irrelevant.)

Comment: This question is *not* about whether sensitive information should be released; it's about where to publish a practical, not very innovate paper. This doesn't seem to answer the question. We have no reason to think the information in the paper is sensitive. (Not everything in the field of InfoSec is)

Comment: Well, I read the OP's question suggesting it could contain sensitive information.  Unfortunately for you and me, it would be unwise for the OP to respond to resolve the debate, if so, as it would compromise the security.  So I'm leaning towards protecting things first.

Comment: @MarkJ If the paper contained any sensitive information, OP wouldn't have posted it on his web page, because that would be **stupid**.

Comment: FYI - I'm not publishing an exploit, just some OPSEC that people overlook in some systems.