# Does Google Scholar link to post-print PDFs lodged on academia.edu or ResearchGate?

Tags: preprint, google-scholar

I'm a big fan of how Google Scholar puts links to full text PDFs of journal articles that are indexed on the internet next to the link the publication page of academic publishers. This means that people who find a reference to a paywalled article in Google Scholar that they do not have access to can still read a PDF from elsewhere on the web.

I've been preparing post-prints of various articles for this purpose. If I post them to academia.edu or ResearchGate, will Google Scholar index them?

Comment: whatever you do, [don't](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16870/researchgate-an-asset-or-a-waste-of-time) [use](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47481/what-should-i-do-if-someone-is-claiming-my-research-on-researchgate) [research gate](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24127/should-i-send-a-cease-and-desist-letter-to-researchgate). put your papers on a personal website (if you own the rights) and create a [google scholar profile](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/citations.html) to ensure that the papers are indexed by google scholar.

Comment: @henning personal websites are not that suitable, either. They tend to disappear quickly and/or go down and/or have errors (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/asi.10018/abstract). It is better to use a preserved archive such as [arXiv](http://arxiv.org), [figshare](http://figshare.com), and [zenodo](http://zenodo.org),

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, it will.

See for example:

[image]

Or:

[image]